# Cordova fileupload not working on Android, $_FILES is empty

Tags: php, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

I am using the cordova filetransfer plugin to upload some pictures to server. It works well on my localhost (Android & iOS), but on my server it only works on iOS. With Android the $_FILES array is empty...

The filetransfer plugin fires the uploadSuccess callback, but i can't get the picture server side...

Server side:

```
public function upload_img_api(){
    file_put_contents('test.txt', print_r($_FILES, true)); //<-test.txt returns empty array :(
    $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    $extension = strtolower(substr($path_parts['extension'], 0, strpos($path_parts['extension'], "?")));
    $extension = ($extension) ? ".".$extension : ".jpg";
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    $image_w = $image_size[0];
    $image_h = $image_size[1];
    $megapixel = $image_w * $image_h;
    $ratio = $this->getResizeRatio($megapixel);
    $image_name = "api_image_".time().$extension;
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], DENT_UPLOAD_TEMP.$image_name)){
        die(json_encode(array('Result' => "ERROR", "MESSAGE" => 'COULDNT FIND FILE')));
    }
    $thumb_path = $this->generate_thumbnail(DENT_UPLOAD_TEMP.$image_name, DENT_UPLOAD_TEMP.'thumb_'.$image_name);
    $resize_image_path = $this->generate_thumbnail(DENT_UPLOAD_TEMP.$image_name, DENT_UPLOAD_TEMP.$image_name, array($image_w/$ratio, $image_h/$ratio));
    die(json_encode(array('file_name' => $image_name)));
}
```

Any advice?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I set the cordova fileupload plugin option to: *chunkedMode = false* it works... I changed te *fileKey* as well, now you have to check for *$_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"]* on server side.

Here are the working options:

```
options.fileKey="fileUpload";
options.fileName=fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
options.httpMethod="POST";
options.chunkedMode=false;
```

Hope it helps others :)